# Best practice to mimic a linux rootfs without root permission on an existing system

Tags: arch-linux, chroot, container, root-filesystem, fakeroot

I have access to a user account of a ubuntu server. However it's really inconvenient to work without root permission (which means that cannot install packages) and I am more familiar with archlinux than ubuntu. I think that I can run a container or chroot under my user directory and simulate the root access in it. Here are some possibilities (as far as I know):

1. Run a LXC. It requires complex configuration and I haven't tried that.
2. Use proot. Here is what I've tried: `fakeroot tar -xzf archlinux-bootstrap-x86_64.tar.gz --numeric-owner` to `rootfs.x86_64` and `proot -S rootfs.x86_64`. But when I tried to run some command like `pacman-key --init` I get strange error `==> ERROR: pacman configuration file '/etc/pacman.conf' not found.` - The file is there and the program fail to find it. When running other commands the problem is similar.
3. Use bwrap. I tried `bwrap --unshare-all --share-net --bind root.x86_64 / --dev /dev --proc /proc --tmpfs /tmp --uid 0 --gid 0 bash`. This time the issue is like I don't have permissions when doing lots of things. Like when running `su` I get `su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted`.

So what's the best practice to do this? Sorry for I don't know what this behavior is actually called so I have to describe it in this awkward way.

Comment: Use lxc. That's meant to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You still won't have root access with `chroot`. You can install applications in `$HOME/.local/bin` or some other directory and export it to `PATH` variable or ask your admin to install required packages.

Comment: @davidt930 that's not true. At least not true for Linux namespaces, and that is underlying all three proposed solutions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I wonder If it is possible to use lxc without root. That requires installing lxc to my home dir and get it to work.

Comment: ah! I lxc was already set up on your system!

Comment: no you couldn't. That wouldn't set up subuids correctly.

Comment: I will ask the server administrator to install lxc then...